# double datatype+iphone

Tags: iphone, types, double

i have a one application i know The range of a double is `**1.7E +/- 308 (15 digits).**`but in my application i have to devide text box 's value to **100.0** my code is

```
double value=[strPrice doubleValue]/100.0;
NSString *stramoount=[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%0.2f",value ];
```

when i devide **34901234566781212** by **100** it give me **349012345667812.12** but when i type
**349012345667812124** and devide by **100** it give me by **100** it give me **3490123456678121.00**  which is wrong whether i change datatype or how can i change my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
NSDecimalNumber * dec=[[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:value.text locale:  [NSLocale currentLocale]] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100" locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];  
NSLog(@"%@",dec);
```

instead of `Double`

Answer (score 6):

The number 349012345667812124 has 18 decimal digits. the `double` format only provides slightly less than 16 decimal digits of precision (the actual number is not an integer because the format's binary digits do not correspont directly to decimal ones). Thus it is completely expected that the last 2 or 3 digits cannot be represented accurately, and it already happens when the literal "349012345667812124" is parsed to the `double` format, before any calculations happen.

The fact that you get the expected result with the number 34901234566781212 means nothing; it just happens to be close enough to the nearest value the `double` format can represent.

To avoid this problem, use the `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber` types.